# Is there a (easy) way to find the cause of a display issue on Select2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-select2

New developper on RoR, I’m using Select2 to display some companies or departments.
Select2 was working fine for some weeks, and now, display is broken on every select2 input.
I used github history to detect why it’s failing now, but no indications of modifications which can explain that.
It's displaying a very small square or nothing. However, selecty2 is working when I click on the small square for exemple.

[small square display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbGib.png), 
[Select2 working but display is broken](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0bvt.png)

I used Github History `pomber` and inspect all files concerned. Nothing to explain why the display is broken now. Is the a way to detect the cause of the issue ? 
I'm using Bootstrap 4 with rails 5.2.1

app/javascript/components/select2.js :

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'select2';
import 'select2/src/scss/core.scss';
import 'select2-bootstrap4-theme/dist/select2-bootstrap4.css';


$('.select2-form').select2({
  theme: "bootstrap4"
});


// Requiring CSS! Path is relative to ./node_modules
```

app/javascript/packs/application.js

```
import '../components/select2';
```

app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= action_cable_meta_tag %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all' %>
    <%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'application', media: 'all' %> 
    <%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'application' %>

    <!-- bootstrap animation carousel -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- bootstrap animation carousel -->

    <!-- Select2 -->
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Select2 -->

  </head>

  <body>
    <%= render 'shared/navbar' %>
    <%= render 'shared/flashes' %>
    <%= yield %>
    <%= render 'shared/footer' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>
    <%#= javascript_pack_tag "map" %>
  </body>
</html>
```

I expect the input should be display correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If it used to work, and now it doesn't, you can [git bisect](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect) to determine which commit introduced the regression. When that is done, you should be able to pinpoint the guilty piece of code, again by adding the changes in this commit one by one and see when the regression pops up. Then you might be able to understand the reason for the regression.